Python XML findall() search/parsing issue
Trying to parse an XML report file in my Gitlab runner and the logic is failing on the line below. Simplified the code so I can post for help.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

test_xml = '''
<FVDL xmlns="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/fvdl" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      version="1.12" xsi:type="FVDL">
    <CreatedTS date="2024-07-10" time="00:54:53"/>
    <Build>
        <Test/>
    </Build>
    <Vulnerabilities>
        <Vulnerability>
            <Kingdom>Security Features</Kingdom>
        </Vulnerability>
        <Vulnerability>
            <Kingdom>Encapsulation</Kingdom>
        </Vulnerability>
    </Vulnerabilities>
</FVDL>'''

fortify_xml_root = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(test_xml)).getroot()

# Works (element found) everywhere except my container in Gitlab
for vulnerability in fortify_xml_root.findall(".//{*}Vulnerability"):
    print("Found 'Vulnerability' element: " + str(vulnerability))

I confirmed it is working perfectly on Windows and Linux, in both Python 2 and 3 in various environments, including online interpreters. The problem is indigenous to my Gitlab runner which is using a RHEL 8 image with Python 2. It's definitely related to the regex/XPath, because if I remove the namespace from the XML and simplify the regex/XPath in the findall() to match it, it works. Could it be related to the underlying env's regex/XPath library?

Support for the namespace wildcard syntax ({*}) was introduced in Python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#xml.

Your code works as you said. I would try findall(xpath, ns):
fortify_xml_root = ET.fromstring(test_xml)
ns = {'': 'xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/fvdl', 'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}

# use findall with the namespace
for vulnerability in fortify_xml_root.findall(".//{xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/fvdl}Vulnerability", ns):
    print("Found 'Vulnerability' element: " + str(vulnerability))
    #print("Found 'Vulnerability' element: ", vulnerability.tag)

